# I need a JavaScript procedure that reverses the following procedure

Tags: javascript, encoding

I have the following function that encrypts a string and I was hoping for a function that reverses the process.

```
function encryptStr(thisString)
        {
            retString = "";
            /* Make retString a string of the 8-bit representations of 
               the ASCII values of its thisCharacters in order.
                       EXAMPLE: "abc" --> "011000010110001001100011"
                                 since the ASCII values for 'a', 'b' and 'c' 
                                 are 97=01100001, 98=01100010 and 99=01100011
                                 respectively
            */
            for (i = 0, j = thisString.length; i < j; i++) 
            { 
                bits = thisString.charCodeAt(i).toString(2);
                retString += new Array(8-bits.length+1).join('0') + bits;
            }
            /* Compress retString by taking each substring of 3, 4, ..., 9 
               consecutive 1's or 0's and it by the number of such consecutive
               thisCharacters followed by the thisCharacter. 
               EXAMPLES:
                    "10101000010111" --> "10101401031"
                    "001100011111111111111" --> "0011319151"
            */
            retString = retString.replace(/([01])\1{2,8}/g, function($0, $1) { return ($0.length + $1);});

            return retString;
        }
```

I tried to make a function and I'm probably doing it wrong because it's 50 lines already. I'm realizing that there's tons of error checking that needs to go on. For instance, I just realized a potential problem because JavaScript characters don't span the entire 127 ASCII values. Should I just give up? Is this a futile problem?

Comment: This code is leaking a lot of variables. It also appears it can be reversed.

Comment: @alex: What does "leaking a lot of variables" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find the numbers in the string which are not `0` or `1`. Then, *expand* them in the opposite way that the original function collapsed them. You can again use `String.prototype.replace()` here with a replacement function...

```
str.replace(/([2-9])([01])/g,
           function(all, replacementCount, bit) {
              return Array(+replacementCount + 1).join(bit);
           });
```

Then, simply decode the bit stream back into characters with `String.fromCharCode()`. You'd need to chunk the stream into 8 bit chunks, and then perform the conversion. I chose to use `Array.prototype.reduce()` as it's quite suited to this task. Alternatively, you could use `String.fromCharCode.apply(String, chunks.map(function(byte) { return parseInt(byte, 2); }))` to get the resulting string.

Something like...

```
str.split(/(.{8})/g).reduce(function(str, byte) { 
                            return str + String.fromCharCode(parseInt(byte, 2)); 
                         }, "");
```

Put it together, and you get a function like...

```
function decryptStr(thisString) {
    return thisString.replace(/([2-9])([01])/g,
    function (all, replacementCount, bit) {
        return Array(+replacementCount + 1).join(bit);
    }).split(/(.{8})/g).reduce(function (str, byte) {
        return str + String.fromCharCode(parseInt(byte, 2));
    }, "");
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Af9q/).

Also, remember to place `var` in front of your variable declarations, otherwise those variable identifiers will leak to the containing scope until they're resolved (which is usually the global object).